# run an inluded files in parallel on same target

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

my target is to be able  to configure multiple iis website on the same target and in parallel.
each website has multiple tasks that configures it, like creating app pool, creating website, setting the website app pool, create the needed directory paths, creating virtual directories, bindings....

so as i need to create multiple websites, which means i need to loop over a bunch of tasks, so i have set these all these tasks in a separate file and in my main playbook i have created a loop which import the file for each website.

but i endup with a serial execution, i want to be able to create websites in parallel.

i didn't find anyway to achieve this as the async is not supported on ansible block

so is it possible to be done with ansible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is a module called async -- I believe this is something you are looking for

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html

This module will help you to run the tasks in parallel. Ideal for creating "n" of websites is IIS -- that are independent.